# How to populate listview and play audio file

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'am trying to populate listview from audio files and want to play the clicked item. It's not working. Any help.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

public static File file; 
private List<String> filelist;
ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.list_item);
    final ListView musiclist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneMusicList);

    MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>();  


        final String targetPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        file = new File( targetPath + "/AudioRecorder" ) ;
        File list[] = file.listFiles();

        // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
         for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
            {
             MyFiles.add( list[i].getName() );
            }

        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MyFiles);

         musiclist.setAdapter(adapter);

musiclist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        //checking the position of item in list
        Object listItem =     musiclist.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+ musiclist, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                playSong(targetPath + MyFiles.get(position));
    }
});
}

    private void playSong(String songPath) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         try {
                mp.reset();
                mp.setDataSource(songPath);
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <ListView
        android:id="@+id/PhoneMusicList" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

This is my latest layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/PhoneMusicList"
      android:layout_width="223dp"
      android:layout_height="334dp" />

  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/play_pause"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:src="@drawable/pause"/>
```

---

I have created an already functioning app which displays ListView items and when an item in the list is selected, it then opens new activity. Inside the new_activity I have TextView and Image button displaying the audio buttons which is play, pause, & stop. the TextView functions perfectly but the image buttons refused to play audio file from raw folder. I have many audio files in the raw folder and want to assign each to each ListView that will open each new activity. Please help me edit this ListViewAdapter code below to play, pause, & stop playing each audio file.

How do I edit this NewActivity.java to populate it with songs from raw folder? I will highly appreciate your support thanks.

```js
public class NewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String TAG = "NewActivity ----- ; " ;
    // Store instance variables
    private String title;
    private int page;
    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        TextView mDetailTv = findViewById(R.id.textView);


        //get data from previous activity when item of activity is clicked using intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String mActionBarTitle = intent.getStringExtra("actionBarTitle");
        String mContent = intent.getStringExtra("contentTv");

        //setctionBar Title
        actionBar.setTitle(mActionBarTitle);
        //get text in text textView
        mDetailTv.setText(mContent);

        //ok we are done,




    public void  play(View v) {
        if (player == null) {
            player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song_1);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Tune Playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    stopPlayer();
                }
            });
        }
        player.start();
    }
    public void pause(View v) {
        if (player != null) {
            player.pause();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Tune Paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
    }
    public void stop(View v) {
    stopPlayer();
    }
    private void stopPlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
            player.release();
            player = null;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Tune Stoped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        stopPlayer();
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the problem you are facing, i mean are you getting any error?

Comment: try below solution and let me know if you face any problem

Comment: problem im getting is the application doesn;t open, it crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following code.

```
public class Recording_List extends Activity{

    ListView mListView;
    ImageView mPlayPause;

    private File file;
    private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

    private static final String MEDIA_PATH = new String(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AudioRecorder/");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recordlist);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.recordList);
        mPlayPause = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.play_pause);

        file = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir();
        }
        File list[] = file.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            myList.add(list[i].getName());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        mListView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                playSong(MEDIA_PATH + myList.get(position));
            }
        });

        mPlayPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    if (mp != null) {
                        mp.pause();
                        mPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (mp != null) {
                        mp.start();
                        mPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void playSong(String songPath) {
        try {
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(songPath);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Iam using only one layout file with listview as posted in the question. I trie to add Imageview to the layout. I'am getting errors @ custom_list_item, @ R.drawable.play , R.drawable.pause.I added two icons to the drawable.Can u suggest on Layout xml files needed. Last error is on mhandler ..(mupdateTimetask) that mupdateTimetask cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: @Sumit, you don't need to use `mupdateTimetask`. So delete it, i have updated my answer you can check that. and instead of using custom list item you can use `simple_list_item_1`. for that also i have updated my answer so just check it and let me know.

Comment: same error: "unfortuanetly yourapp has stopped". Iam attaching my layout activity in my question again.

Comment: @ innocentkiller : thanks it worked after i made some changes in layout xml, now im trying to figure out if there is some way to display some customised text instead of file names in the listview keeping files at the backend. do suggest.

Answer (score 0):

you should change targetPath as below

```
targetPath =targetPath + "/AudioRecorder/" ;
```

or replace

```
playSong(targetPath + MyFiles.get(position));
```

with

```
playSong(targetPath +"/AudioRecorder/"+ MyFiles.get(position));
```

Comment: this doesn't work. i mean application crashes before it opens.

Comment: ..@ zohreh the change you suggested didn't make any difference, the app still crashes

Answer (score 0):

Recorder With List View of that files in Ringa_Singa folder.
when you will stop the play you have to go back to update the list otherwise it's okay.
You can play the latest record from that play button

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_record_audio);
    //List View
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    //Recording events on button
    startbtn = findViewById(R.id.btnRecord);
    stopbtn = findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
    playbtn = findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    stopplay = findViewById(R.id.btnStopPlay);
    stopbtn.setEnabled(false);
    playbtn.setEnabled(false);
    stopplay.setEnabled(false);
    mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/RingaSinga";
    int entryNumber = 1;
    File mFile = new File(mFileName + "/RingaSinga_" + String.valueOf(entryNumber) + ".wav");
    while (mFile.exists()) {
        entryNumber++;
        mFile = new File(mFileName + "/RingaSinga_" + String.valueOf(entryNumber) + ".wav");
    }
    this.mFileName = mFile.getAbsolutePath();
    //List all files on list view
    File directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    mFile = new File( directory + "/RingaSinga" );
    final File list[] = mFile.listFiles();

    for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
    {
        myList.add( list[i].getName() );
    }
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, android.R.id.text1, myList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter); //Set all the file in the list.
    //Click listner on List item
    final File finalMFile = mFile;
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(RecordAudio.this, ""+ listView, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            playSong(finalMFile + myList.get(position));

        }
    });


    startbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (CheckPermissions()) {
                stopbtn.setEnabled(true);
                startbtn.setEnabled(false);
                playbtn.setEnabled(false);
                stopplay.setEnabled(false);
                mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
                try {
                    mRecorder.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
                }
                mRecorder.start();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                RequestPermissions();
            }
        }
    });
    stopbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopbtn.setEnabled(false);
            startbtn.setEnabled(true);
            playbtn.setEnabled(true);
            stopplay.setEnabled(true);
            mRecorder.stop();
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
    });
    playbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopbtn.setEnabled(false);
            startbtn.setEnabled(true);
            playbtn.setEnabled(false);
            stopplay.setEnabled(true);
            mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
                mPlayer.prepare();
                mPlayer.start();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording Started Playing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
            }
        }
    });
    stopplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
            stopbtn.setEnabled(false);
            startbtn.setEnabled(true);
            playbtn.setEnabled(true);
            stopplay.setEnabled(false);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing Audio Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_AUDIO_PERMISSION_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                boolean permissionToRecord = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                boolean permissionToStore = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                boolean permissionToRead = grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                if (permissionToRecord && permissionToStore && permissionToRead) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

public boolean CheckPermissions() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), RECORD_AUDIO);
    int result2 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result2 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

}

private void RequestPermissions() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(RecordAudio.this, new String[]{RECORD_AUDIO, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_AUDIO_PERMISSION_CODE);
}
private void playSong(String songPath) {
    try {
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mPlayer.reset();
        mPlayer.setDataSource(songPath);
        mPlayer.prepare();
        mPlayer.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
    }
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mPlayer.release();
}
```